# What is this plant with a "ball" like head of purple flowers?

Tags: identification

I took the photo below in a country park so I don't know what it is called.  Is there a term for the shape besides "ball" like?  I tried searching for general descriptions online but I couldn't find anything

[image: Purple Flower]

Edit:
I had used a link to flickr before SE used imgur.com for hosting images. I think I'd moved the images around in flickr which broke the url. I only had two photos of this flower so it's not too bad.  You can find this and other flower images on my [flickr account](https://www.flickr.com/search/?tag_mode=all&sort=relevance&user_id=92157978%40N06&tags=flower&view_all=1)

Comment: in addition to the flower a photo of the leaf is always helpful

Comment: Your image is toast, any chance of an update?

Comment: Sorry about the image not working.  I'm just looking into figuring out which one it was.  I still have the images so I should get it sorted soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a type of primrose, the [Primula denticulata (drumstick primrose)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primula_denticulata), owing to the flower morphology.

Comment: Thanks.  That got me on the right track and I was able to find what I'm quite sure is the same plant.  I wasn't sure about the accepted way to put that in so I decided to edit your answer rather than submitting my own.